Azure Purview Api returning 404
I am using below microsoft learn page to query some data using rest api calls, I tried to fetch glossary list by clicking try it button. I have an azure purview resource created in my subscription with data sources and the glossary exist.
MS learn page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/datamapdataplane/glossary/list?view=rest-purview-datamapdataplane-2023-09-01&tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs
API I am trying - GET {endpoint}/datamap/api/atlas/v2/glossary
whenever I login using my Azure account to which I have below access but I am still getting response code 404
I do not want to use service prinicipal want to use an AD user.
I have bleow permission on Purview collection
Role-NHA-Dev-Purview-Collection-Admin
Role-NHA-Dev-Purview-Data-Source-Admin
Role-NHA-Dev-Purview-Data-Reader
Role-NHA-Dev-Purview-Data-Curator
can you please guide me what wrong I am doing here ? I have added screenshots the


I created few sample glossaries in my Azure Purview account as below:

Initially, I too got "404 error" when I ran the REST API by clicking Try it button on Microsoft Learn page:
GET https://purviewname.purview.azure.com/datamap/api/atlas/v2/glossary


The error occurred as MS Learn site is adding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/datamapdataplane/glossary/ as prefix to request URL that is making it invalid and not found.
Alternatively, you can make use of below PowerShell script that generates token and use it to retrieve list of glossaries successfully like this:
$resourceGroupName = "rgname"
$purviewAccountName = "accname"

$token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://purview.azure.net" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Token

$endpoint = "https://$purviewAccountName.purview.azure.com/datamap/api/atlas/v2/glossary?api-version=2023-09-01"

$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $token"
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $endpoint -Headers $headers -Method Get
    $response
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to retrieve glossary list. Error: $_"
}

Response:

You can also generate token using managed identity as you mentioned in this MS Q&A. Make sure to assign at least Purview Data Reader role to user/managed identity for listing glossaries.
